# Extbase not recognizing custom JsonView

Tags: php, json, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am using typo3 7.6.
I can't make extbase take my custom JsonView, it seems like it does not recognize it.

I overwrite the default JsonView like this:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView as ExtbaseJsonView;
class JsonView extends ExtbaseJsonView
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $configuration = [
    'jobs' => [
        '_exclude' => ['pid'],
        '_descend' => [
            'place' => [
                '_only' => ['name']
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
}
```

EDIT: According to this [docu](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-2/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/View/JsonView.php#L60-L157)

Now I don't understand why I still get this output as Json:

```
[{"description":"Owns products","pensum":100,"pid":55,"test":"Product","title":"Product Owner","uid":1}]
```

One the pid is still there even though it is in the exclude field and the place does not get outputed. It seems like extbase is ignoring my override, but I don't know why and no errors are ever thrown. I put my custom JsonView into Classes/View/JsonView.php

My models are:

Job

```
/**
* Job
*/
class Job extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
/**
 * title
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $title = '';

/**
 * description
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = '';

/**
 * pensum
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $pensum = 0;

/**
 * test
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $test = '';

/**
 * place
 *
 * @var \Vendor\SfpJobs\Domain\Model\Place
 */
protected $place = null;

// below getter and setter

}
```

Places

```
/**
* Places
*/
class Place extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

/**
 * name
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $name = '';

/**
 * numberOfEmployees
 *
 * @var int
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $numberOfEmployees = 0;

/**
 * acquired
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $acquired = null;

// below getter and setter

}
```

Controller

```
/**
* JobAjaxController
*/
class JobAjaxController extends ActionController
{

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $defaultViewObjectName = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView::class;

/**
 * jobRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\SfpJobs\Domain\Repository\JobRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $jobRepository = NULL;

/**
 * placeRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\SfpJobs\Domain\Repository\PlaceRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $placeRepository = NULL;

/**
 * action list
 * This function
 *
 * @param \Vendor\SfpJobs\Domain\Model\Job $job
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $jobs = $this->jobRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('jobs', $jobs);
    $this->view->setVariablesToRender(array('jobs'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, there were two mistakes one was my fault another seems to me like poor documentation.
I still used the default Jsonview in my controller
so I needed

```
protected $defaultViewObjectName = \Vendor\Jobs\View\JsonView::class;
```

instead of

```
protected $defaultViewObjectName = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView::class;
```

The second was my faulty Jsonview config.
In the [docu](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-2/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/View/JsonView.php#L60-L157) it reads

```
'variable3' => array(
 *          '_exclude' => array('secretTitle'),
 *          '_descend' => array(
 *              'customer' => array(
 *                  '_only' => array('firstName', 'lastName')
 *              )
 *          )
 *      ),
```

I thought that the variable3 could be an array but this is not true. The notation for arrays is like this:

```
'somearrayvalue' => array(
 *          '_descendAll' => array(
 *              '_only' => array('property1')
 *          )
 *      )
```

so in the end I had this config

```
protected $configuration = [
    'jobs' => [
        '_descendAll' => [
            '_exclude' => ['pid'],
            '_descend' => [
                'place' => [
                    '_only' => ['name']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```